# No puedo utilizar el comando pip en CMD

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Quiero utilizar el comando pip para crear ejecutables de python pero cuando intento utilizar este comando por ejemplo para actualizar pip por medio de "python -m pip install -U pip" me lanza este error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado: 'c:\\users\\PALANACONDA\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_internal\\build_env.py' 
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Uso Anaconda Navigator para programar con Spyder, pero al parecer el anaconda deniega el acceso al comando "pip" ¿Pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error es porque al entrar al CMD, no entras como administrador y no tienes permisos, necesitas añadir al final de la instrucción "--user", como te está indicando el error.